# CSS Resize Height Issue

Tags: css, resize

Kinda stumped here. Working with the following code:

```
<style> 
  section {
      resize: both;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #DEE5FF;
  }
</style>

<body>
    <section data-annotation-id="801R" class="textWidgetAnnotation" style="transform: matrix(1.80882, 0, 0, 1.80882, 0, 0); transform-origin: -43.3357px -107.897px 0px;  left: 43.3357px; top: 108.897px; width: 308.308px; height: 11.387px;"></section>
</body>
```

As you can see, the height is set at 11.387px upon load. Problem is, once it's resized, that height will no longer go below 15px. Have no clue why this is happening and have looked around too much. Hoping someone has encountered this before so I can move on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/we1p9tbc/) you can use to see the problem.

Comment: I would say it's the minimum height for the resize icon .. I don't think we can technically go to 0 (it's the same for the width by the way)

Comment: I don't think so, because if you remove the transform styles, the same effect is happening at a smaller scale, which demonstrates the icon can get as small as I need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

There was no solution that I could find, so I just included the jQuery UI script in my blade and used their javascript resizable feature instead. Works fine.